# Namespacing my code in Go

Tags: go

I'm writing a fairly simple application in Go, more as a learning tool than anything else.

What I'd really like to do is to organise my code somewhat - for example, I've separated out some Hipchat API commands into a separate file. Right now, it's still under the `main` package, but I'd prefer to move it (namespace it) into a kind of subpackage. The thing is, Go seems to think that such a package should live in my `$GOPATH`, despite it not being relevant to any project besides the one it's being written for.

I'm probably trying to misuse the package functionality, so if so, what's the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Whats wrong with it to be under $GOPATH? Thats how Go works. Code is either under $GOROOT/src/ or $GOPATH/src/

Comment: Putting it under GOPATH seems odd since it's inherently part of one project and one project only. It may just be that I'm not yet used to Go paradigms, though.

Comment: Then put it under `$GOPATH/src/my/project/subpackage`. For other languages you set up your directory-structure as well (like src/main/java/... for maven), for Go thats $GOPATH and the structure beneath it. You can either use a different GOPATH for all of your projects or you get used to a single one, but you definitely have to set a GOPATH if you want to write anything larger than a single package (`main`).

Comment: Check out the directory-structure at https://golang.org/doc/code.html, thats what you should use. $GOPATH isn't fixed though, you can set it to whatever you want, but you __need__ to set it so Go finds your sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the pointers from tkausl in comments left on my question, I figured out the way to achieve exactly what I wanted. I moved my project to reside in `$GOPATH` and then accessed the sub-package via `import subpackage from "project/subpackage"`.

Wouldn't have got there for a while without that help! Just a case of learning Go's way of doing things.